# How to get a list of allocated jobs on a node in slurm?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

Is there a way to see a list of jobid's scheduled to be run on a node that shows state ALLOCATED ?

Or otherwise a list of jobids with their expected start time and to which node they are allocated ?

Slurm 16.05.11 -Bull.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the jobs currently running on a node, or a list of nodes, with

```
squeue -w <nodelist>
```

and you can see the nodes on which jobs will start with

```
squeue --start
```

Comment: Thanks! I am reading the docs, but the amount of new information is just overwhelming, specially trying to figure out witch of the many s-commands does what. Until now I am a great fan of scontrol :)